# Issue with automated slicing on triangulated mesh

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, modifiers, boolean-modifier

My goal is to obtain the profile of an **triangulated mesh** through a cutting plane

[image]

I have a script that automatically applies a Solidify modifier (without which it won't work) and then a Boolean modifier. It works well when I add a plane and scale it only on the X/Y axes.

```
import bpy

# duplicate selected object in active scne
obj = bpy.context.active_object
new_obj = obj.copy()
new_obj.data = obj.data.copy()  
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_obj)

# Hide original object
obj.hide_set(True)

# 1 modifier solidify
solidify_mod = new_obj.modifiers.new(name="Solidify", type='SOLIDIFY')
solidify_mod.thickness = 0.001

# 2 modifier boolean
bool_mod = new_obj.modifiers.new(name="Intersection", type='BOOLEAN')
bool_mod.operation = 'INTERSECT'
bool_mod.solver = 'FAST'

# Plane as target for boolean
plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
bool_mod.object = plane

# Hide plane
plane.hide_set(True)

# Apply solidify
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
new_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Solidify")

# Apply boolean
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
new_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Intersection")

# Convert Grease epencil
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')
bpy.context.object.data.layers["Cube_001_Lines"].line_change = -20
```

[image]

But if I rotate the plane, it no longer works: the object is only partially cut. Applying transform to the plane or the object does not work either. I'm looking for some clues to understand where this problem comes from and how to fix it.

I know that there is the bisect tool for this, but I am looking to achieve the same result without entering edit mode and in an automated way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the slices need to have a thickness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bmesh bisect operation instead of a boolean. All is commented below.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']

object = bpy.context.object

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

# convert the object to a bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(object, depsgraph)

# the plane in the object coordinates
mat = object.matrix_world.inverted() @ plane.matrix_world
plane_co = mat @ plane.data.vertices[0].co
plane_no = mat @ plane.data.polygons[0].normal

# bisect the mesh with the plane
result = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, 
            geom=bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:], 
            plane_co=plane_co, 
            plane_no=plane_no)

# get the cut part
cut = result.get('geom_cut')

# translate the indices of the result so that vertex indices start from 0
# (cut result have its indices in the whole mesh object)
index_map = dict()
verts = []
for i, v in enumerate((v for v in cut if type(v) == bmesh.types.BMVert)):
    index_map[v.index] = i
    verts.append(v.co)
    
edges = []
for i, e in enumerate(e for e in cut if type(e) == bmesh.types.BMEdge):
    edges.append((index_map[e.verts[0].index], index_map[e.verts[1].index]))
    
# create a mesh with these vertices and edges
cut_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('cut')
cut_mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])
cut_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('cut', cut_mesh)
cut_obj.matrix_world = Matrix(object.matrix_world) # the cut in the same space as the original
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cut_obj)
```

Resulting cut on Suzanne (poor Suzanne...).

[image]